# Send a bitmap image in an email

Tags: android

I looked over similar questions and tried to write this simple code.
This code takes an bitmap image of the view then allows the user to attach it to email. 
for some reason I get the message "can't attach an empty file" in the email application. 
I'm fairly new to this and I read a few examples and tried different things but non worked. I suspect that something might be wrong with my path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.asamater.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="Q1" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="Q2" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:text="Q3" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton5" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton6" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:text="Q3" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton7" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton8" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:text="Q4" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton10" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton9" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/radioButton9"
            android:onClick="email" />

    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
 package com.example.asamater.myapplication;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void email(View view){
    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(z,totalHeight,totalWidth);
    String path = saveImageToStorage(bitmap);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "ammar5001@gmail.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "report");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ");

    emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
            "/"+ path);
    Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);


    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));

}


private String saveImageToStorage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/req_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image-Report.jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    Log.i("myActivity", "" + file);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return root + "/req_images" + fname;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

}

Comment: please reduce your code to a minimal example that reproduces the problem

Comment: your not actually creating the file

Comment: so how is the file created??

Comment: I love it, the guy says he researched, makes a valid go at it, seems a bit lost, but is trying.  He includes the code he has created, but the SO thugs gotta vote him down.  sigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manifest needs:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.asamater.myapplication" >
    <!-- Permissions need to be added too-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
</application>
```

Replace your email method with this then delete the saveImageToStorage Method:

```
public void email(View view){
    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(z,totalHeight,totalWidth);

    // Create the file directory
    File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/req_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    // For multiple files you want to create a timestamp so the name is unique
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_H_mm_ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date curDate = new Date();
        String displayDate = format.format(curDate);
    String fname = displayDate+ "_Image-Report.jpg"; // now this is dynamic

     // create the file in the directory
     File file = new File(myDir, fname);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "ammar5001@gmail.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "report");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ");

   /*
    * The important part where you create the file and save it
    */
    emailIntent.setType("image/*"); // accept any image

     try {
            boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
            if (fileCreated) {
               // write the bitmap to that file
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("SAVE FAILED", "could not save file");
        }

     // then attach the file to the intent
     emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));

 }
```

Comment: ok I did so, and I am still getting the same error. I was just reading up some more on it. so do I need to set the permission for the storage in my manifest file??

Comment: @AmmarSamater i simplified your code more, see update. And please post your error

Comment: saveImageToStorage(bitmap) is returning null, so path is null.

Comment: @AmmarSamater like i said see my update, you don't need that method if you copy the email method i have provided above

Comment: ok I used the update, I'm still seeing " cannot attach an empty file" in the google email app.      also, the variable 'bitmapFile' does not exist, so I changed it to file? should be something else?? there are three File variables in the method which I'm finding confusing

Comment: ahh, typo in my code. see update i used wrong variable name `bitmapFile `instead of `file` when saving the output

Comment: still same error. Could it be due to permissions in the manifest??

Comment: @AmmarSamater yes add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: that was the issue, thanks lots. will tried to up vote but not enough rep yet.

Comment: This code worked only the first time. after that it would not email a new image. only the one that was taken the first time the code executed. I corrected the issue and simplified the method. Answer is posted below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88500/discussion-between-inner-class7-and-ammar-samater).

Comment: awesome support @inner_class7!

Answer (score 1):

This work!

```
public void email(View view){
    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(z,totalHeight,totalWidth);

    File file = BitmapSaver.saveImageToExternalStorage(this, bitmap);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "ammar5001@gmail.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "report");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ");
    emailIntent.setType("image/*"); // accept any image
    //attach the file to the intent
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));

}
```

The BitmapSaver class:

```
 /**
 * Created by ASamater on 01/09/2015.
 */
 public class BitmapSaver {


public static File saveImageToExternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    long n  = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });

    return file;
}
```

}